# percentile function by row in PBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, percentile

Not sure why DAX Percentile function here doesn't seem to work?

The simple table contains the following.

```
-Name   Score   
-a  1   
-b  2   
-c  3   
-d  4   
-e  5
```

I've tried the following measure:

```
90% Percent? = PERCENTILE.INC('Table'[Score],0.9)
```

The table I am hoping to see is this since 4.6 is the 90th percentile of the scores

```
-Name   percentile
-a  4.6
-b  4.6     
-c  4.6     
-d  4.6     
-e  4.6
```

I've tried

```
90% Percent? = PERCENTILE.INC('Table'[Score],0.9)
```

Answer (score 1):

In this situation filter on `Name` should be removed with `ALL(Table[name])` or `ALL(Table)` if you want to display other columns from `Table` query.

The measure would look like this:

```
Percentile = CALCULATE( 
                PERCENTILE.INC(Table[Score], 0.9),
                ALL(Table[Name]) 
)
```

Result:

[image]